# dhcpd on a /30 subnet compains about lease not available all the time

Tags: linux-networking, dhcp-server

I am having trouble with dhcpd.

for a large WAN, with lots of 255.255.255.252 subnets, we are using DHCP to push a single IP out to all these sites.

Each Subnet has a definition as follows

```
subnet 10.91.17.0 netmask 255.255.255.252 {
            option routers 10.91.17.1;
            option subnet-mask 255.255.255.252;
    pool {
            allow members of "Devices";
            range 10.91.17.2 10.91.17.2;
    }
}
```

Everything works, however the syslog fills with messages as below. See also the tcpdump.

The Client never changes at the site, so it should gets the same adresses every time it requests it.

Any thoughts why I keep getting the messages please

thanks

```
DHCPREQUEST for 10.91.17.2 from 00:18:6e:3a:0f:00 via 10.91.17.1: lease 10.91.17.2 unavailable.
DHCPNAK on 10.91.17.2 to 00:18:6e:3a:0f:00 via 10.91.17.1




15:46:10.347927 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22511, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 281)
    10.205.148.2.bootps > 10.205.148.5.bootps: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:18:6e:3a:0f:00, length 253, xid 0x1, Flags [none] (0x0000)
          Client-IP 10.91.17.2
          Gateway-IP 10.91.17.1
          Client-Ethernet-Address 00:18:6e:3a:0f:00
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Request
            Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether 00:18:6e:3a:0f:00
15:46:10.348202 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29802, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    10.205.148.5.bootps > 10.91.17.1.bootps: [bad udp cksum 0xbb73 -> 0xbe92!] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0x1, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
          Gateway-IP 10.91.17.1
          Client-Ethernet-Address 00:18:6e:3a:0f:00
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: NACK
            Server-ID Option 54, length 4: 10.205.148.5
            MSG Option 56, length 31: "requested address not available"
```

Comment: What is your DHCP-Server?  Is your gateway the same as your DHCP server?  Have you checked that something is not already on that IP?

Comment: the Gateway is a router, and the router has the DHCP server set as the "dhcp helper"

Comment: the client gets the IP address first time.. but then when it comes to renew, is told the address us unavailable